# Collect averages Java Stream in one shot

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I'm trying to find how to collect averages of each field in a list of objects in one liner.

Here is what I'm trying to perform:

```java
public class Value {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  // rest of the class
}
```

Now let's assume I have `List<Value> values = getMillionValues();`

I know that to get average for one field, I can do following:

```java
int averageOfA = values.stream().mapToInt(Value::getA).average()
```

What do I need to do in order to get averages for all values w/o repeating line above for each variable?

Maybe there are some other libraries, like Guava, that can help to perform these kind of operations?

Comment: Use a for loop.

Comment: Creating a new stream for each field is likely to be substantially cheaper than any of the alternatives, which will involve creating at least an array object (the cheapest option) for each Value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seriously, use a for loop.

```
int count = 0, sumA = 0, sumB = 0, sumC = 0;
for (Value v : values) {
    sumA += v.getA();
    sumB += v.getB();
    sumC += v.getC();
    count++;
}
double avgA = ((double) sumA) / count;
double avgB = ((double) sumB) / count;
double avgC = ((double) sumC) / count;
```

Seriously, use the code above.

---

Having said that you should use the code above, you can do it with a stream.
You need a few value holders (the average is a `double`, so your `Value` class can't store the averages):

```
class AveragesResult {
    public final double a, b, c;
    public AveragesResult(double a, double b, double c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
class AveragesIntermediate {
    public final double a, b;
    public AverageIntermediate(double a, double b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Now that we have the boilerplate out of the way (for good measure, you should implement `hashCode`, `equals` and `toString`, and add some getters), we can finally write the stream in a short and compact way:

```
values.stream().collect(teeing(
   teeing(averagingInt​(Value::getA), averagingInt​(Value::getB), AveragesIntermediate::new),
          averagingInt(Value::getC),
          (ir, avgC) -> new AveragesResult(ir.a, ir.b, avgC));
```

Wasn't that hard, right? Make sure you have statically imported all the Collector functions (it looks a lot uglier with all those `Collectors.`) and you are using Java 12 (`Collectors.teeing` is new in Java 12).

Don't use that, use a good old `for` loop.

Comment: But, but, but... shiny streams? (I entirely agree with using a for loop).

Comment: You can do it. But I don't recommend it.

Comment: When you have created your `AveragesResult` class anyway, you may use it like `values.stream().collect(AveragesResult::new, (ar, v) -> { ar.a += v.getA(); ar.b += v.getB(); ar.c += v.getC();} , (ar1,ar2) -> { ar1.a += ar2.a; ar1.b += ar2.b; ar1.c += ar2.c; })`. It becomes more readable when you create `add` and `merge` methods in the `AveragesResult` class.

Comment: This calculates the sum.You need to keep track of the count as well (but you won't need the count in the result), so maybe create a new class that also holds a count field?